# GCM not receiving untill run SuperVPN

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have written an application, and in this application I can send a notification to users. In the first version, there were no problems. Then I made revisions with the same key, and I began experiencing problems.

Some devices no longer receive any notification, and one of these devices is my device. Later, I discovered that my device and others are no longer accepting any notification from GCM service, even though I put the new version of my app with GCM along with the new key or any app has GCM.

This problem has been reported to me by others who have updated to the new version of my app . But some users who updated the application works with them without any problems. I mean for some users, the app continues to work correctly.‏

when I run SuperVPN app all notifications delivered ! 
so two devices connected to same router 
first one get notifications normally 
other one not receiving without SuperVPN

**manifist.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.labyb.englishwordeachday"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.WordActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".AllWordsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.AddsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_adds"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.AllWordsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.TranslateActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_translate"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test_new" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.ReminderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.SetReminderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_set_reminder"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.mybroadcast" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.RemindersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reminders" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.SpeachActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_speach"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.LevelsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_levels" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.WebActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_web" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.labyb.englishwordeachday.GcmIntentService" />

        <receiver android:name=".StartUpBootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
package com.labyb.englishwordeachday;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**GcmIntentService.java**

```
    package com.labyb.englishwordeachday;

    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
    import com.labyb.englishwordeachday.classes.Adds;
    import com.labyb.englishwordeachday.classes.DatabaseHandler;

    public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
        public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        DatabaseHandler db;
        static int counter = 0;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString(), "Send error: " + extras.toString(), "Send error: " + extras.toString(), "Send error: " + extras.toString(), "Send error: "
                        + extras.toString(), "Send error: " + extras.toString(), "Send error: " + extras.toString(), "Send error: " + extras.toString(), "Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString(), "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString(), "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString(),
                        "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString(), "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString(), "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString(),
                        "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString(), "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString(), "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                // Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ " +
                // SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // try {
                // Thread.sleep(5000);
                // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // }
                // }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                sendNotification(extras.get("word_id").toString(), extras.get("m1").toString(), extras.get("m2").toString(), extras.get("m3").toString(), extras.get("m4").toString(), extras.get("m5")
                        .toString(), extras.get("m6").toString(), extras.get("m7").toString(), extras.get("level").toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    long[] vibraPattern = { 500, 500, 500, 500 };

    private void sendNotification(String word_id, String m1, String m2, String m3, String m4, String m5, String m6, String m7, String level) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (m4.equals("v1")) {

        } else if (m1.equals("newadd")) {


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AddsActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("قد يهمك ايضا")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(m2)).setAutoCancel(true).setTicker("قد يهمك ايضا").setVibrate(vibraPattern)
                    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.ewed)).setContentText(m2);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
            counter = counter + 1;

            db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            db.addAdd(new Adds(m3, m2));// /hereeeeeeeeeeeeee
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", word_id);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(m1)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(m1)).setAutoCancel(true).setTicker("كلمة إنجليزية جديدة").setVibrate(vibraPattern)
                    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.ewed)).setContentText(m2);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
            counter = counter + 1;

            db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            db.addNewWord(word_id, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, level);// /hereeeeeeeeeeeeee
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any hints in the responses/error reponse to your server?

Comment: no no all are success :(